# How notifications work with multiple users?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, multi-user

When there are multiple users in an Android device, how the notifications work?

- The notifications are simultaneous for all users?
- There are only notifications for the active user and notifications for other users are disabled until the other users log in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Notifications appear for all accounts of a single user at once.
- Notifications for other users do not appear until they are active.

Source: [Supporting Multiple Users](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multi-user.html#applying_the_overlay)

Comment: Confirmed by this answer: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/117438/show-notifications-for-all-users

Answer (score 1):

The current session is suspended before switching to the new user profile. This is what I noticed at least for the guest profile.