# Does switching user accounts in Lollipop affect battery life or performance?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, battery-life, stock-android, motorola-moto-g, multi-user

I recently updated my Moto G2 to Android
Lollipop via OTA update. I've successfully
installed the update(around 500mb i
guess). I saw the new feature of adding
new Guest and New user acccounts just
like the one in PC's so that one user
doesn't get access to other user apps or
data.

So, say if I have some 10 apps running in
my owner account and it drains battery
while running in background. But then if I
wanted to switch to a guest account to
lend my phone to a friend or some
stranger, I cannot see any apps running in
the guest account in the recent apps
section that was open in the owner
account. So my question is,

Will those 10 apps that are opened and still
running in the background in my owner
account drain my battery while the phone is
in Guest mode?

or only the app that runs under my guest
account will have an effect on my phone's
battery usage.

Comment: Good points. Basically the question behind is: What happens to running apps when switching users – do they keep running (in background), or will the "originating user's" session be "frozen"? I have no LP device to test this out myself. Is your device rooted? Do you have ADB available?

Comment: No my device is not rooted..i just updated through motorola ota.

Comment: OK, that most likely rules out my idea for investigation. // As I find it pretty interesting, I've mentioned (and linked to) your question in our chat room as well. Some of our "power users" are actually devs who might be able to answer this question (and probably will, given some time to see it). Good luck(y) – and I'm curious for the answers as well!

Comment: A pointer might be found [in this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/88548/16575), which states at least for the guest account: *The current session is suspended before switching to the new user profile.* If that's a general rule, it would mean the "suspended profile" should not eat any battery – as it's suspended (i.e. inactive).

Comment: @Izzy thanks for the link. But by suspending do you mean the apps don't stay in the memory(RAM) and the state of the app is not saved. If it does stay in the memory, then switching to other account and playing a HD game in other account will have any performance issues. Because I can see the apps still in the recents tab even after switch accounts. But I don't know whether it runs in the background and eats up the RAM. I noticed no lags with 1GB of memory and some small apps running in both accounts, but curious just to know android does managing multiple user account app sharing in the RAM.

Comment: First, I was just pointing to another answer – so the "idea" is not mine. Second, the exact meaning of suspending was not given there; thinking of the "sleep modes" a laptop/computer has, it could be "suspend to RAM" or "suspend to disk". Both had in common that no CPU cycles, network traffic, etc. would be caused by the "suspended session". Third, an app even stays in the "recent list" when you closed it from somewhere else: "recent" means "recently used", not "currently running". Last, "suspend" would mean the state of apps saved to be restored later.

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/105069/do-applications-run-in-user-profiles-that-are-not-active-run-in-background-pro/105071#105071

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, the multiuser feature DOES drain quite a lot of battery. Here is a screenshot of my battery stats - I have not logged in as the other user since my last full charge.

[image: battery stats for multiuser]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

Comment: @stringray Is this the phone's default Battery settings? What version do you use? because the Battery usage in my LP 5.0.2 looks different and displays a graph at the top..and the strange thing is I'm currently using my main account(Lucky) which doesn't even show the `User: Guest` in my batter usage list..so i'm not sure about this behaviour..

Comment: @Lucky Yes, I have not changed anything specific in my setting. My phone is an LG G3 with LP 5.0. I do have the graph at the top, I just scrolled down to the app-specific battery usage. I tried to log in to the other account and stop all running apps now, I'll see if that makes any difference. Worth noting is that I don't get User: Guest in the list either, just my other account that my girlfriend uses from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that owner account and new user account runs concurrently and their by consuming more battery, How did I know, first I installed some apps on my owner account like bbm, Whatsapp and imo, I got these apps connected to internet and working, I switched the account to another user account and install other apps and have it working. Finally I switched to the guest account and send messages to the apps running on the owner account and new user account. I switched off the internet to make sure the messages I send to the bbm and Whatsapp won't get there while am switching the account. To confirm my curiosity, the messages were already there when I switched the accounts.
With that I conclude that dual user consumes more battery.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you must understand that the smartphone actively manages all the apps and accounts without interruption. That means if you are creating multiple accounts then your smartphone will have to manage all accounts actively. That is the reason why your smartphone is draining more battery.

Try the following things:

- Clear cache of Phone.
- Always close the background running apps if not required.
- Close the unwanted applications that are running anonymously without your permission. To do this go to Settings >> Apps and select the app you do not want to use or run and simply click on stop.

These are the few things to remember for long life of battery.

Comment: This doesn't authoritatively answers "*Will those 10 apps that are opened and still running in the background in my owner account drain my battery while the phone is in Guest mode? or only the app that runs under my guest account will have an effect on my phone's battery usage?*"