# Android MultiUser: show notification for all users

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, notifications, multi-user

I have an LG Nexus 5 with Android 6.0.1, the device is rooted and with XPosed installed (if this can be useful to the question).

I have 2 different Android users, one is personal and one is for work. I'm using 2 different accounts instead of Android for Work because I care of keeping the data of the 2 accounts divided at max as possible.

The only (the very only) problem is that I do not receive notifications from an user until I switch it back to it. Is there a configuration, an app, a root procedure, even an XPosed module which can bring the notifications from the 2 accounts togheter?

Comment: I don't think you can do much here. It is written [here](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multi-user#effects) that "*Notifications for other users do not appear until active*"

Comment: I noted something, on my Nexus 5 the notification are not displayed for the unactive account, but the notification LED blinks if any. Every time I see the LED blinking I unlock the phone and found nothing to see, then I switch account and I find the notifications there

Comment: this answer confirms notifications are only shown for the current user: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/117438/show-notifications-for-all-users